# Не получается отправить файл post запросом в fetch

Tags: javascript, api, fetch

Возникла проблема с отправкой файла через post запрос. Я отправляю сообщение,но у меня выходит ошибка 403.Буду рад любой помощи!

```js
document.querySelector('.upload_files').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
  const fileInput = document.getElementById("file").files[0];
  console.log(fileInput);
  const cont = {
    "project_id": 14497,
    "file": document.getElementById("file").files[0]

  }
  let url = 'https://brizo.ru/api/v1/field-file';

  fetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer qOzco4BasgCsktWyYBkHfHCftcC0iLEWfwiawx2XpiRsGt8d8c12MrRj43sI',
        headers: {
          'X-Brad-Test': 'true'
        },
        cache: 'no-store',
        mode: 'no-cors'

      },


      body: JSON.stringify(cont)
    })
    .then(response => console.log(response));
})
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="#">
  <p>
    <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
  </p>
  <p>
    <input class="upload_files" type="submit" value="Отправить" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: попробуй использовать formData https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects